# Actions must be plain objects. when firebase auth.signOut()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

I have a React-Redux project I am working on that is causing me this error when trying to use the signOut() method from firebase auth:

`Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

The weird thing is that the login action dispatches correctly.

Here is my index.js in which I set up the store:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import root from './store/reducers/root'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import firebase from './config/firebase'


const store = createStore(root,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirestore, getFirebase })),
    reduxFirestore(firebase),

  )
  + window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
)

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: firebase,
  dispatch: store.dispatch
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here the action creator (which as you can see is the same as for login but without parameters):

```
export const login = (credentials) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase()
        const email = credentials.email
        const password = credentials.password
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(() => dispatch(
                {
                    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
                }
            ))
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch(
                    {
                        type: 'LOGIN_ERROR',
                        err
                    })
            })
    };
}


export const logout = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase()
        firebase.auth().signOut()
            .then(() => dispatch(
                {
                    type: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS'
                }
            ))
        // .catch((err) => {
        //     dispatch({
        //         type: 'LOGOUT_ERROR',
        //         err
        //     })
        // })
    };
}
```

Here is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    authError: null
}

const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: null
            }
        case 'LOGIN_ERROR':
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: action.err.message
            }
        case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: null
            }
        // case 'LOGOUT_ERROR':
        //     return {
        //         ...state,
        //         authError: action.err.message
        //     }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default user
```

And this is the component in which I map the dispatch to the props and call the logout function:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Drawer, makeStyles, ListItem, ListItemText, List } from '@material-ui/core'
import { logout } from './../store/actions/auth'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    temporaryDrawer: {

    }
})


const TemporaryDrawer = (props) => {


    const classes = useStyles()

    const list = ['Log Out']



    const handleOnClose = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        props.setState(false)
    }


    return (
        <Drawer className={classes.temporaryDrawer} open={props.state} anchor="right" onClose={handleOnClose}>
            <List>
                {list.map(text =>
                    <ListItem button key={text} onClick={props.logout}>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                )}
            </List>
        </Drawer >
    );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        logout: () => dispatch(logout())
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TemporaryDrawer);
```

I have spent now a couple of hours trying to figure out what is wrong and all the answers on the internet are not applicable to my case.

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT

OK, as I suspected has something to do with the redux dev tool. If I remove `+ window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()` it work fine. How can I set that up properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution,

the store should be created as such:

```
const store = createStore(root,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirestore, getFirebase })),
    reduxFirestore(firebase),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
)
```